# Alterar Configurações Tomcat no Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: tomcat, amazon-aws

Estou com dificuldades atribuir as propriedades de JDBCHealm ao server do tomcat. Como incluir novas propriedades no arquivo server.xml ou no arquivo tomcat-users.xml quando a app esta no servidor da amazon hospedado com o tomcat server como elasticbeanstalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode substituir as configurações da seguinte forma:

Crie um diretório dentro do seu `webapp`, e cole seu `server.xml`. Após isso, crie um xml: `server-update.config`, com o código abaixo:

```
container_commands: 
  replace-config: 
    command: cp .ebextensions/server.xml /etc/tomcat7/server.xml
```

Essa informação pode ser encontrada em:
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files/

Observe que da forma acima, o seu server.xml irá substituir por completo o existente, se desejar apenas substituir algumas configurações ou inserir outras, observe a forma abaixo, do soEN:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30598373/1997073

Comment: tem que criar um diretório dentro do meu projecto é isso? não consegui fazer funcionar ainda as configs

Comment: Isso... no seu projeto web você deve ter um diretório chamado `webapp`, crie dentro dele este diretório.

Comment: Deu certo ! muito obrigado estava a horas tentando!

Comment: +1 pelo feedback! ;)